# macOS: private JRE should ignore global extension directories

Tags: java, macos

When launching a Java application with a private JRE 1.8 on macOS, according to the logged parent classloader jar files from following locations are also loaded: `~/Library/Java/Extensions/`, `/Library/Java/Extensions/`, `/System/Library/Java/Extensions/` and `/usr/lib/java/`.

We want our Java application to be as independent of the system configuration as possible. How to prevent loading `.jar` and `.jnilib` files from above locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html) the locations are defined by the system property `java.ext.dirs`. Setting this system property using `-Djava.ext.dirs=$JRE_HOME/lib/ext` only loads the .jar files from there (assuming `JRE_HOME` points to the private JRE).